# Interactive Grid - filter on column with multiple values (Oracle APEX)

Tags: oracle, filter, oracle-apex

Its any possible to enable multi value filters for columns in oracle apex (oracle apex bug# 25565254).

Thanks in advance

Regards

Muthurasu N

Answer (score 0):

If there's a bug, create your own filtering by creating items (for each column you'd like to filter) and adding them to report's `WHERE` clause. For example:

```
where (employee_name = :P1_EMPLOYEE_NAME or :P1_EMPLOYEE_NAME is null)
  and (job           = :P1_JOB           or :P1_JOB           is null)
```